# How to check if invisible items are visible?

Tags: applescript

How do I check in AppleScript, if invisible objects are visible?
If visible, do: `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles 0`
in invisible, do: `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles 1`.

That should be one script, so I can change the visible with one click. Is that possible with AppleScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to grgarside's script, this doesn't need you to restart the Finder, just refresh open windows.

Can be saved as an app or in Automator, as a Service.
I have it as a Service, triggered on  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>    <kbd>H</kbd>  from System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services - which required me to change the 'Hide Finder' key command in …Shortcuts > App Shortcuts to something other than default.

To add as Service, launch Automator then File menu > New.
Select Service in the dialog then drag Run Applescript to the new Automator window.
Copy/paste the script inside the `on run` - replacing (* Your script goes here *) & Save. It needs only the default parameters for everything else.

[image]

In System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services it will be added as the last line. Set any trigger key command you like.

[image]

If you use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>H</kbd>  the same as me, you'll need to change Hide Finder to something else - I just used a garbage shortcut as I never need that command…

[image]

```
set newHiddenVisiblesState to "YES"
try
    set oldHiddenVisiblesState to do shell script "defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles"
    if oldHiddenVisiblesState is in {"1", "YES"} then
        set newHiddenVisiblesState to "NO"
    end if
end try
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles " & newHiddenVisiblesState


tell application "Finder"
    set theWindows to every Finder window
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in theWindows
        set this_item to item i of theWindows
        set theView to current view of this_item
        if theView is list view then
            set current view of this_item to icon view
        else
            set current view of this_item to list view

        end if
        set current view of this_item to theView
    end repeat
end tell
```

The script itself reads the current state of the invisible flag (less elegantly than grgarside's version but just as effectively;) then toggles each open window to another view type - list, icon etc then back again.

**Edit:** Just refreshing the windows no longer works in El Capitan, you now have to restart the Finder.
New version for El Capitan

```
set newHiddenVisiblesState to "YES"
try
    set oldHiddenVisiblesState to do shell script "defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles"
    if oldHiddenVisiblesState is in {"1", "YES"} then
        set newHiddenVisiblesState to "NO"
    end if
end try
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles " & newHiddenVisiblesState & "; killall Finder"
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. But can you explain, what the script is doing, the near background of the mode of operation? And how can I add a service with a shortcut?

Comment: I tweaked the answer...

Answer (score 0):

This sets the value of b to true or false depending on the current value of AppleShowAllFiles:

```
[[ $(defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles) = 1 ]] && b=false || b=true
```

Therefore, you can create a script such as this:

> ```
> do shell script "[[ $(defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles) = 1 ]] && b=false || b=true
> defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool $b"
> tell application "Finder"
>     quit
>     delay 0.2 -- without this delay there was a "connection is invalid" error
>     reopen -- open a new default window
>     activate -- make Finder frontmost
> end tell
> ```

All credit to Lauri in [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20495287)

Comment: And what does the scrip does here? For what is the "-bool $b" and the "[[ $(defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles) = 1 ]]"